# HDFS access error from Cosmos global instance

Tags: fiware, filab, fiware-cosmos

I'm trying to access to my HDFS space by using the Hadoop fs commands.
I've followed the instuctions from:
http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/BigData_Analysis_-_Quick_Start_for_Programmers

But after successfully logged in, the hadoop commands on fs fails.

```
$ ssh tcappellari@cosmos.lab.fiware.org

[tcappellari@cosmosmaster-gi ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/tcappellari
ls: Cannot access /user/tcappellari: No such file or directory.
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Such a QSG link is a bit obsolete, the Cosmos portal is now running at https://cosmos.lab.fiware.org/, which I guess you finally used. Can you confirm that point, please?

Comment: @frb. Yes, I'm using the Cosmos portal at cosmos.lab.fiware.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HDFS user space (`/user/tcappellari`) should be enabled now. This was an error when provisioning the account, possibly because the cluster was on safe mode.

Comment: Now `ls` command works, but any attempt to create a directory fails (Safe mode exception). The cluster is still on safe mode.